# Show list of options using JavaScript prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

In JavaScript, is it possible to show a list of options to click using a `prompt` window, instead of a list of options to be typed in manually?

I'd like to present each option as a button, instead of asking the user to type the options manually (as shown here):

`var OptionChosen = prompt('Enter 1, 2, 3, or 4:')`

Comment: Proper, browser-based custom modal dialogs are impossible to create - _apparently_ due to security concerns.  You'd have to mimic one using a DOM element.

Comment: Is it compulsory for you to use a prompt?  I would just code my own popup using javascript and a DOM element.  You also have fancy popup libraries for jquery

Comment: @AntonGarciaDosil Specifically, I want to create a modal dialog box with a list of buttons that the user can select, so that the value of a variable is set based on the user's choice (just like the JavaScript prompt window).

Comment: @AndersonGreen I believe you cannot do that with a Javascript prompt. As PSR said you may use jQuery dialog.  There is a huge amount of jQuery extensions implementing modal windows.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that, but you could use [jQuery dialog box](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/API/1.8/Dialog&redirect=no) instead.

Example jQuery:

```
var selected = 0;
$('#dialog').dialog({
  title: "Prompt",
  buttons: {
    "First": function() {
      selected = 1;
    },
    "Second": function() {
      selected = 2;
    },
    "Third": function() {
      selected = 3;
    },
    "Fourth": function() {
      selected = 4;
    }
    // ..............
  }
});
```

with html:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Choose your option</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a variable to the output of a JQuery dialog box?

Comment: You can have different buttons here.You can set return differenbt values