# Pause the video, ask a question and resume if the answer is correct

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorry if this newby question is already asked, but I couldn't find the answer in the other questions. What I am trying to do is having a video in the html and pausing it to ask a question, if they choose the correct answer from 2 options they can continue watching the video. I manage to do it by using a prompt, but I need 2 options rather than a text answer. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

This is how I made it with prompt:

```
<video id="video" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The script

```
var video = document.getElementById ("video");
video.ontimeupdate = function () {
 var currentTime = Math.floor (video.currentTime);
 if (currentTime == 3) {
 video.pause ();
 var r = prompt ("Question?");
 if (r.toLowerCase () == "Answer") {
 video.currentTime = 4; 
 video.play ();
 } else {
 video.currentTime = 0;
 video.play ();
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't do it in prompt. You might find [this response helpful]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556030/show-list-of-options-using-javascript-prompt].

Comment: If you want to have questions over the video and to pause the video. You should have an input field that uses position: absolute/relative to go over the video.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions! I now found a working solution and will update the question with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this HTML and javascript snippet

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");

        video.ontimeupdate=function(){
        if(Math.floor(video.currentTime) == 3){
            document.getElementById("question").style.display="block";
            video.pause();
            video.removeAttribute("controls")
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("question").style.display="none";
        }
    }
    function submit(){
        if(document.getElementById("op1").checked == true){ //if option 1 is correct
            video.currentTime = 4;
            video.play();
            video.controls = true;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("op2").checked == true){ //if option 2 is correct
            document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML="Wrong Answer";
        }
    }
```

```html
<video id="video" controls autoplay allowfullscreen="0">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
   
    <section id="question" style="display: none;">
        <p class="que">What is corona?</p>
            <input type="radio" id="op1" name="options"><label for="virus">virus</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="op2" name="options"><label for="bacteria">bacteria</label><br>
            <font style="color: red;" id="warning"></font><br>
            <button id="submit" onclick="submit()">submit</button>

    </section>
```